# How to remove comma from a html div class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove all commas from a HTML div class. is it possible to remove commas without modifying the HTML content via CSS or javascript?

div class

```
.test a:link {
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML content

```
<div class="test"><a href="https:google.com">here</a>, <a href="https:google.com">new</a>, <a href="https:google.com">test</a></div>
```

Comment: No, you're going to have to use JS - or some sort of serverside logic before the HTML is sent to the browser.

Comment: Do you mean "is it possible to remove commas without modifying the HTML content, via CSS or javascript?" If not, no.

Comment: @WillD can you please guide me how to do that?

Alex
in that case, can we make all comma colors to white?

sorry english is not my first language. will it be possible to do it using javascript or css? or javascript and css both combined?

Comment: How about fixing the code that is generating that extra comma instead of putting work-arounds in place.

Comment: @nbstrat app/system generating same content for another part. i want to keep another part the same and modify for some part (remove commas).

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean you can't edit the HTML, or if you can't use CSS/JS? If you mean you can't edit the HTML you can do it with JS but your question is not clear.

Comment: it's the html content i cannot edit. i can edit the CSS and js. anyways @WillD gave me the solution. thank you all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JS will replace the innerHTML of the div with a copy of itself where all instances of `,` have been replaced by an empty string (effectively deleted).

See [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). This uses a very simple "regular expression" aka Regex to find all the commas.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.test');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '');
```

```html
<div class="test"><a href="https:google.com">here</a>, <a href="https:google.com">new</a>, <a href="https:google.com">test</a></div>
```